# Non Pro CoinBase API Invalid Signature

Tags: api, coinbase-api

i've been trying to get some data from the non pro CB via their API.

I've been able to get data from coinbase pro, with the code below, adding the passphrase, but no dice with CB...

I keep getting invalid signature :(

Any idea what i could be missing?

```
const signedMessages = async (timestamp, meth, requestPath) => {
  const secret = process.env.cb_all_read_secret;
  const method = meth.toUpperCase();
  const body = '';

  const message = timestamp + method + requestPath + body;
  const key = Buffer.from(secret, 'base64');
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
  const cb_access_sign = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');
  return cb_access_sign;
};

const listAccounts = async () => {
  let timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const signed = await signedMessages(timestamp, 'GET', '/v2/accounts');
const url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts';

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'CB-ACCESS-KEY': process.env.cb_all_read_key,
      'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signed,
      'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    },
  };
  console.log(options);

  try {
    const data = await fetch(url, options);
    const resultat = await data.json();
    console.log(resultat);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error.message);
  }
};

listAccounts();
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd check is that your computer's clock is up to date i.e. not > 30 seconds behind the API server.

Comment: checked it already, we have the same time. At first i had a time stamp error, flooring it made it go away..

Answer (score 0):

coinbase documentation is frustrating at best.
In one place I saw the method you're using being documented.

```
var what = timestamp + method + requestPath + body;

// decode the base64 secret
var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');

// create a sha256 hmac with the secret
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

// sign the require message with the hmac
// and finally base64 encode the result
return hmac.update(what).digest('base64');
```

When I went to find it again I found the following: [documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication) which does the signing a little differently:

```
var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", apiSecret).update(message).digest("hex");
```

Notice the lack of a `base64` buffer and the digest is `Hex`.

I modified your code and was able to get the wallets with view permissions. I would probably create a sign function using the code in the link provided including the body for any options you need to include.

```
const signedMessages = async (timestamp, method, path) => {
    const apiSecret = '...';
    const bodyStr = '';
    let message = timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + '/v2/' + path + bodyStr;
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(message).digest('hex');
};

const listAccounts = async () => {
    let timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const signed = await signedMessages(timestamp, 'GET', 'accounts');
    const url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/';

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': '...',
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signed,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        },
    };
    console.log(options);
    try {
        const data = await fetch(url, options);
        const resultat = await data.json();
        console.log(resultat);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error: ', error.message);
    }
};

listAccounts();
```

but guess what...

the ["deprecated" node api](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node) does it the same way (that's where I found this signing method before I found the documentation) and it was last updated 4 years ago. Go figure.