# Coinbase API - Cannot POST

Tags: powershell, coinbase-api

What's wrong with this? Why can't I POST a buy? I keep getting 401 Unauthorized. The API has the correct permission (wallet:buys:create)

I should point out, that my GETs work, I can read all information from the account.

```
$time = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/time'
$epochtime = [string]((Invoke-WebRequest $time | ConvertFrom-Json).data).epoch

$method = 'POST'
$requestpath = '/v2/accounts/xxxxxxxx-3ecb-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx/buys'
$endpoint = "https://api.coinbase.com/$($requestpath)"
$secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

$sign = $epochtime + $method + $requestpath
$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($secret_key)
$computeSha = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sign))

$signature = ([System.BitConverter]::ToString($computeSha) -replace "-").ToLower()

$header = @{
"CB-ACCESS-SIGN"=$signature
"CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP"=$epochtime
"CB-ACCESS-KEY"='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

$body = '{"amount": "10", "currency": "XLM", "payment_method": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "commit": "true", "quote":"false"}'
function Get-CoinBase($method, $endpoint, $header, $body)
{
  $result = Invoke-WebRequest $endpoint -Headers $header -Method $method -body $body -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
  write-host $APImethod -f yellow

  return $result
}

$AccountBAL = Get-CoinBase -method "POST" -endpoint $endpoint -header $header -body $body
```

Comment: why not use the exchange api instead of the coinbase api?

Comment: what is the error in your message? invalid signature/key/timestamp?

Comment: I am going to just the CoinBasePro API also but I really just want to figure this out for the non-pro Coinbase API. The error returned is "invalid signature" but as far as I can see, I am forming the sig correctly? All my GETS work fine with the same $requestpath variable which forms part of the sig.

Comment: take a look at this post. it seems cb and cbpro might sign a little differently 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69714766/non-pro-coinbase-api-invalid-signature

Comment: You might be on to something here! The time server is 1 hour behind my PC. I'm in Ireland and daylight savings is due to kick in Sunday (We roll back 1 hour). If this is the issue and it just started working Monday, I would have been stumped!

Comment: Tried changing the time on my laptop to match the time of the time server but no dice. My problem is different to that post you suggested Travis, in that I can GET data from the API no problem, just not POST.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the time, but the method of signing.

Comment: Ah yes, but why would my current method of signing work for GET and not for POST?

Answer (score 1):

I missed it before, you're not including the body in your hash. When you sign you need to include the body options.

```
$sign = $epochtime + $method + $requestpath
```

should be

```
$sign = $epochtime + $method + $requestpath + $body
```

here is their example

```
var message = timestamp + req.method + req.path + req.body;
//create a hexedecimal encoded SHA256 signature of the message
var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", apiSecret).update(message).digest("hex");
```

Comment: Very well spotted. I missed that, but still getting an "invalid signature" error. I'm defining $body as a hashtable then converting to JSON then concatenating it to the signature. I'm assuming it's supposed to be concatenated as JSON?

Comment: I use node and looking at the working npm module it's doing `json.stringify(body)` it looks like the result would be exactly what your `$body` variable holds in the OP (unless it doesn't like the quotes around 10 since it's a number)... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify that being said, it would seem it would just take the body provided to confirm your signature. I wish their docs were more clear about the signing.

Comment: Oh man you are a life saver, thank you